# Prevent Tcl from crashing on unknown command

Tags: tcl

I'm doing `eval` on the content of file. The file is made out of labels which I parse. Each line has a label, and I have a `proc` defined for each label, so that the `eval` succeeds. However, sometimes users add new labels and then the `eval` command fails, because of unknown command.

Is there a way to prevent Tcl from crashing when trying to `eval` an unknown command?
Ideally, it should allow me to substitute with my own defined behaviour - such as priting an error and continuing with the `eval`.

---

**EDIT**:

Unfortunately, I can only use Tcl 8.4.
I tried doing the following, [as suggested here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/unknown.htm):

```
proc handle_unknown_label {cmd args} { ... }
```

and then:

```
rename unknown _old_system_unknown
rename handle_unknown_label unknown

catch {set ret [eval $x]} err

rename unknown handle_unknown_label
rename _old_system_unknown unknown
```

but I still get the same behavior for the `eval`, and it prints the following errors:

> procedure unknown is a protected proc and will not get renamed
>   procedure unknown is a protected proc and will not get overriden
>   procedure unknown is a protected proc and will not get renamed
>   procedure unknown is a protected proc and will not get overriden

Comment: not applicable but if you are reading a file and evaling it you may as well just source the file instead, no?

Comment: in what environment is this Tcl interpreter? I'm not familiar with that "protected proc" error.

Comment: @glenn Interesting. So this could be something that was disabled in my firm?

Comment: The only thing that came to mind was that you're boxed into a safe interpreter, but even that does not prevent you from defining an `unknown` proc. Your Tcl interpreter must be specially built to be extra-paranoid.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm stating the obvious, but `eval`'ing a file is dangerous: any user can embed `[exec whatever they wish]` into such a file.

Much better would be to read those "labels" and use a giantic switch or a hash map or whatever to execute a predetermined command. Catching non-existing "labels" also becomes a non-issue.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. However, this is not really an answer to my question and I think this should be a comment.

Comment: It's a pretty good answer TBH. Keep a list of all the valid labels, if the one you just read is not in that list, call a proc of your own choosing. It solves the problem exactly and adds safety to boot.

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own command called [`unknown`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/unknown.htm), which takes as its arguments all the words that make up the command that can't be found and its args:

```
proc unknown {cmdName args} {
    puts "UNKNOWN COMMAND: $cmdName"
    puts "CALLED WITH ARGUMENTS: $args"
}
```

That's about all you need to do, though you can get fancier with the use of [`namespace unknown`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M22).

Comment: Thanks! Can you give an example of how to use the `namespace unknown` command? I would like to change the handling of unknown commands temporarily, so I would like to know how to change and then restore, the default handling.

Comment: @Amir: Someone's locked you down heavily, so there's not much we can suggest (other than perhaps reading the docs on the hosting system). We've told you the standard mechanism in the language…